# How do I trim specific elements of a list?

Tags: python, list

I've got a list here that represents a line in a file after I split it:

```
['[0.111,', '-0.222]', '1', '2', '3']
```

and I'm trying to trim off the "[" and the "," in the first element and the "]" in the second element. How would I do that? I've started my thought process here, but this code doesn't work:

```
for line in file:
    line = line.split()
    line[0] = line[1:-1]
    line[1] = line[0:-1]
    print(line2)
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.  This is basic string processing.

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  Your posted code fails to run, and your assignment statements do not seem to be aimed toward doing anything useful, replacing one list element with a slice of the rest of the list.  Please revisit your tutorials on list and string.

Comment: You can read about python regular regressions for more help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `replace` to remove the brackets:

```
 lst = ['[0.111,', '-0.222]', '1', '2', '3']

 lst2 = [x.replace('[','').replace(']','') for x in lst]

 print(lst2)
```

Output

```
['0.111,', '-0.222', '1', '2', '3']
```

You also be more specific:

```
lst2 = [x[1:] if x[0] == '[' else x[:-1] if x[-1] == ']' else x for x in lst]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re.sub`:

```
from re import sub

s = '[0.111, -0.222] 1 2 3'
s = sub('[\[\]]', '', s)
print(s.split())
```

Output:

```
['0.111,', '-0.222', '1', '2', '3']
```

If by any chance you would like to remove the comma as well, you can

```
from re import sub

s = '[0.111, -0.222] 1 2 3'
s = sub('[\[\],]', '', s)
print(s.split())
```

Output:

```
['0.111', '-0.222', '1', '2', '3']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could filter only the numeric part of each string with a function like:

```py
def clean(strings):
  def onlyNumeric(c):
    return c.isdigit() or c == '-' or c == '.'
  return list(map(lambda s: "".join(filter(onlyNumeric, s)), strings))
```

Then your example (and many other oddities) could be addressed.

```
>>> clean(['[0.111,', '-0.222]', '1', '2', '3'])
['0.111', '-0.222', '1', '2', '3']
```